# Entity Code First String FK values Uppercase or Lowercase

Tags: ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity, uppercase, lowercase

FK is linked to tbWarehouseUser 1 recording.
There are both lowercase and uppercase values in the tbWarehouseUser table.

How can I solve this problem ?

The classes are as follows;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var model = new Model1();
        var tbWarehouse = model.tbWarehouse.Where(c=> c.sWarehouse == "A1").FirstOrDefault();

        var tbWarehouseUserList = tbWarehouse.tbWarehouseUser.ToList();
    }
```

tbWarehouseUserList.Count record count 1.

1 record is coming. This problem causes sourced?

[Recording picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k27b.png)

```
public partial class tbWarehouse
{

    tbWarehouse()
    {
        tbWarehouseUser = new HashSet<tbWarehouseUser>();
    }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string sWarehouse { get; set; }
    public string WarehouseDescription { get; set; }


    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbWarehouseUser> tbWarehouseUser { get; set; }

}



public partial class tbWarehouseUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string sUserName { get; set; }        

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string sWarehouseName { get; set; }

    public string sUserPass { get; set; }


    public virtual tbWarehouse tbWarehouse { get; set; }


}


public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }
protected void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<tbWarehouse>()
            .Property(e => e.sWarehouse)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tbWarehouse>()
            .Property(e => e.WarehouseDescription)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tbWarehouse>()
            .HasMany(e => e.tbWarehouseUser)
            .WithRequired(e => e.tbWarehouse)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.sWarehouseName)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tbWarehouseUser>()
            .Property(e => e.sUserName)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tbWarehouseUser>()
            .Property(e => e.sWarehouseName)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tbWarehouseUser>()
            .Property(e => e.sUserPass)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
```

}